# Python mapping dictionary to a list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

`prices  = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]`

```
items = [
    {
        “name” : “foo”,
        “price”: 12.3
    }
    {
        “name” : “foo1”,
        “price”: 12.7
    }
    {
        “name” : “foo2”,
        “price”: 20.4
    }
]
```

I am looking to order items based on the prices, so the result should be something like this:

```
result = {
    “<5”: [],
    “<10”: [],
    “<15”: [
        {
            “name” : “foo1”,
            “price”: 12.7
        }
        {
            “name” : “foo”,
            “price”: 12.3
        }
    ],
    “<20”: [],
    “<25”: [
        {
            “name” : “foo2”,
            “price”: 20.4
        }
    ],
    “>25”: []
}
```

So I have made a double loop which works, but I don't think it is super efficient and python way

```
result = []
for i in range(0, len(prices) - 1):
   itm_list = []
      for f in items:
         if f['price'] > prices[i] and f['price'] <= prices[i+1]:
            itm_list.append(f)
      result.append({f'<{prices[i+1]}': sorted(itm_list, key=lambda k: k['price'], reverse=True)})
```

Comment: "works" ? you want a dict you have a list at the end

Comment: What's your question exactly? For improving working code, it'd probably be better to ask on [codereview.se] instead, but first please read [their How to Ask page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) since they work a bit differently. If you specifically want to ask here, we'd need more details like what exactly you think could be improved. And please fix the syntax errors in your code. See [ask].

Comment: Also, minor thing, but in your code you're missing `">25"` in the result.

Comment: On second thought, don't ask on Code Review, cause they only deal with already-working code, and your code isn't quite working.

Comment: I think this is appropriate to ask in SO if it really works, as the code is not lengthy?

Comment: If the price is always an increment of 5, you could just divide by 5 and use that as an index.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually iterate through the dictionaries to achieve linear time complexity:

```
from operator import itemgetter


result = {f'<{price}': [] for price in prices}
dicts = iter(sorted(items, key=itemgetter('price')))
try:
    d = next(dicts)
    for price in prices:
        lst = result[f'<{price}']
        while d['price'] < price:
            lst.append(d)
            d = next(dicts)
except StopIteration:
    result[f'>{price}'] = []
else:
    result[f'>{price}'] = list(dicts)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the given input:

```
items = [
    {"name": "foo", "price": 12.3},
    {"name": "foo1", "price": 12.7},
    {"name": "foo2", "price": 20.4},
]

prices = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Initialize a dictionary `result`. Iterate over all the prices, get the price range, and append all the items that fit the price range.

```
result = {}

for i in range(1, len(prices)):
    mn = prices[i - 1]
    mx = prices[i]

    # append all items with price in range
    result["<" + str(mx)] = [item for item in items if item["price"] < mx and item["price"] >= mn]

result[">" + str(prices[-1])] = [item for item in items if item["price"] > prices[-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about performance time, just cache the loop:

```
for i in range(len(prices)-1):
    list1 = [j for j in items
             if list(j.values())[1] > prices[i] 
             and list(j.values())[1] <= prices[i+1]
             ]
    result[f'<{prices[i+1]}'] = list1

result[f'>{prices[-1]}'] = [j for j in items
                            if list(j.values())[1] > prices[-1]]
```

#Before caching

```
%timeit function_before_cache()
15.4 µs ± 195 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

#After caching

```
%timeit function_after_cache()
83.6 ns ± 2.44 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```